# How to trigger jQueryMobile listview search?

Tags: listview, search, jquery-mobile, filter

I'm working on a listview whose content should be updated by two different ways: a search bar and a select-option filter.

So far, I managed to refresh the listview according to one of these conditions.
Problem is to combine both these options.

Here is an example:

[search: no string] [select: no option]

- Apple
- Banana
- Beans
- Carrot
- Potatoes

Let's imagine that the user uses the search box first. Listview content is updated according to the search string.

[search: "B"] [select: no option]

- Banana
- Beans

Then, the user uses the selectbox. The listview is rebuilt according to the selected option, with a smaller set of items.

[search: "B"] [select: Vegetables]

- Beans
- Potatoes

At this point, I'd like to force the research in order to filter this newer set of items with the search string. I would have liked to get this result:

[search: "B"] [select: Vegetables]

- Beans

I've searched the jqueryMobile API for a method to force the search update process, but without success. Do you know the function I should use to trigger the search ?

Comment: Add select option values - e.g. _vegetable_ - to the main array. Then do a comparison between listview search results and select option value. what do you think?

Comment: you can build your own filter criteria using underscore.js and then pass the results to listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out. Hope this solution works for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/dxS8f/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {

    var listJSON = [
        { item : 'Apple',       category : 'Fruites'},
        { item : 'Banana',      category : 'Fruites'},
        { item : 'Beans',       category : 'Vegetables'},
        { item : 'Carrot',      category : 'Vegetables'},
        { item : 'Potatoes',    category : 'Vegetables'},
        { item : 'Spinach',     category : 'Vegetables'},
        { item : 'Strawberry',  category : 'Fruites'}
    ];

    $.each(listJSON, function(i, field){
        $('#mylist').append('<li>'+field.item+'</li>').listview('refresh');
    });

    var yourFilterFunction = function( text, searchValue, item ){
        var flag = false,
            sCat = null;
            categoryVal =  $("#optCategory").val().toLowerCase();

        $.each(listJSON, function(i, field) {
            if(field.item === text) {
                sCat = field.category;
            }
        });

        flag = (text.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue) > -1) && ((sCat.toLowerCase() === categoryVal || categoryVal === ''));
        return !flag;
    };

    $("#mylist").listview('option', 'filterCallback', yourFilterFunction);

    $("#optCategory").bind('change', function() {
        var inputTxt = $("input.ui-input-text").val();
        $(".ui-input-text").trigger("keyup");
        $.each(listJSON, function(i, field) {
            yourFilterFunction(field.item, inputTxt, $("#mylist").children().eq(i));
        });
    });

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="HelloPage">   
        <header data-role="header" class="header">
            <a href="#" data-rel="back">Back</a>
            <h5>jQuery Mobile</h5>
        </header>
        <div data-role="content">
            <select id="optCategory" data-mini="true">
                <option value="" >Select One</option>
                <option value="Fruites">Fruites</option>
                <option value="Vegetables">Vegetables</option>
            </select>
            <br/>
           <ul id="mylist" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
           </ul>
        </div>
        <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"><h5>&copy; All rights reserved</h5></footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```